# Settings Visibility of Grid Hides Another Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, visibility

I have two grid controls sitting within the same row of a parent grid.

```
<Grid x:Name="grdTimelinePlusControls" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="pgbVideoTimeline" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="7" Background="{StaticResource SecondaryColour}" Foreground="Maroon" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource ExpandContractTimeline}" Grid.Row="1" MouseDown="pgbVideoTimeline_MouseDown" MouseMove="pgbVideoTimeline_MouseMove" MouseUp="pgbVideoTimeline_MouseUp" />
    <Grid x:Name="grdControls" Grid.Row="2" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColour}" Height="40" Style="{StaticResource ExpandHideControls}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stpPlaybackControls" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0">
            <Image x:Name="btnPlayPause" Height="30" Margin="10,5,5,5" ToolTip="Play" Source="Resources/Images/UI/Play.png" MouseEnter="buttonHover_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="buttonHover_MouseLeave" MouseUp="btnPlayPause_MouseUp" />
            <Image x:Name="btnReplay" Height="30" Margin="5" ToolTip="Replay" Source="Resources/Images/UI/Replay.png" MouseEnter="buttonHover_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="buttonHover_MouseLeave" MouseUp="btnReplay_MouseUp" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stpMiscControls" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
            <Slider x:Name="slrSpeed" Width="100" Margin="5,10,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Minimum="1" Maximum="5" Value="3" LargeChange="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ValueChanged="slrSpeed_ValueChanged" />
            <Image x:Name="btnOpen" Height="30" Margin="5" ToolTip="Open" Source="Resources/Images/UI/Open.png" MouseEnter="buttonHover_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="buttonHover_MouseLeave" />
            <Image x:Name="btnFullScreen" Height="30" Margin="5" ToolTip="Fullscreen" Source="Resources/Images/UI/FullScreen.png" MouseEnter="buttonHover_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="buttonHover_MouseLeave" MouseUp="btnFullScreen_MouseUp" />
            <Image x:Name="btnSettings" Height="30" Margin="5,5,10,5" ToolTip="Settings" Source="Resources/Images/UI/Settings.png" MouseEnter="buttonHover_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="buttonHover_MouseLeave" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
<Grid x:Name="grdWorkingTime" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="pgbWorkingTime" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColour}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ForegroundColour}" Width=500 Foreground="Maroon" Margin="5" />
</Grid>
```

I only intend to show one of `grdTimelinePlusControls` and `grdWorkingTime` at a time and with the code as it is above I see both a progressbar (`pgbWorkingTime`) over the top of the various images I have on the two `StackPanels`. However when I change the opening tag of `grdTimelinePlusControls` to be:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdTimelinePlusControls" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed">
```

It stops either grid from showing and I can't understand why. It seems like `grdWorkingTime` must be a child of `grdTimelinePlusControls` somehow but I cant see it, the document outline also shows them at the same level.

This is obviously not all of the code on my page but I wanted to keep it readable... The full page is [here](http://pastebin.com/NwYaab2t%20here)

Answer (score 2):

Is there any particular reason that the two grids are in the same parent grid's row? If you place them in two separate rows with `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />` the 'unused' row should collapse together with the corresponding child grid as you don't intend to show them together at the same time.

Comment: Yep, that works and is a good point... Although I would still like to know why it was behaving weirdly in the original code.

Comment: @blawford: I must say that my initial assumption would have been exactly the same as yours and I would expect the other grid to appear. When you collapse the top grid does it retain the space or is the whole row actually collapsed too?

Comment: The row is collapsed.